# Computing power set and cartesian product: P({a}×{b})

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Compute: P({a}×{b})**

I know ({a}×{b}) is ({(a,b)}) but then what's P({(a,b)})?

help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(\{{(a,b)} \})=\{ \emptyset,\{{(a,b)} \} \} $,
$2^1=2=\vert P(\{{(a,b)} \}\vert$

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhh makes sense now. It's the same. Thanks @Razieh

Comment: you are welcome dear.

Answer (score 1):

The Cartesian product of singleton sets is again a singleton set. The power set of a singleton set contains the singleton set and the empty set.

Comment: Yeah I understand now. Thanks so much.